# TCPClient won't connect from custom class

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine, tcpclient

I'm facing a quite strange problem on Unity 5.2.0f3 64Bits. When I create my own custom class for a `TcpClient` connection, this one never gets connected. This is my simple class:

```
protected override void StartClient(string mod, string ip)
{
    RunClient(ip, mod);
}
private ManualResetEvent connectDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
private void connect_done(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    connectDone.Set();
}

private void RunClient(string ip_host_name, string mode)
{
    try
    {
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient();

        client.BeginConnect(IPAddress.Parse(ip_host_name), 6666, new AsyncCallback(connect_done), client);
        connectDone.WaitOne();
        //Console.WriteLine("Connected");
        SslStream lv_ssl_stream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false,
                                            new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate), null);

        if (authenticate_server(lv_ssl_stream, client))
        {

        }
        else
        {
            // Console.WriteLine("\nCouldn't authenticate the server");
        }

        client.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
}
```

This is a custom class which doesn't inherit from `MonoBehaviour`, because the idea was it to run on a different thread. When I execute the Unity app, the class instance is properly created and also executed (with/out Thread, it's for both the same behaviour).

When the process comes across `client.BeginConnect()` the `AsyncCallback()` is fired, but the `client.connected` is still false.
When I replace `client.BeginConnect()` with `client.Connect()` the process will hang there, and when it's not executed in a different thread, the Unity framework just dumps. (Not Responding)

I developed the class first on .Net 2012 and could execute it with all expected results (no errors).

EDIT:
When I create and ran `TcpClient.Connect()` in `MonoBehaviour`, the `TcpClient` gets connected to my server, but this isn't an solution for me as it's a lot of data which is getting returned.

Has somebody faced this type of problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround for that issue was to create a normal unity C# script, placing there the whole client code.
Unity is still buggy, because the first time the code was copied, it didn't work but commenting out/in it worked (copied code of `RunClient()` )...